# HttpDelete call to API controller is returning a status code of 200 but is not deleting anything

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using the NetCore 3.1 Entity Framework for a gaming website.

I have the HttpDelete controller below that is giving me odd behavior.

When I test it via the Postman program, the API is sending back a status code of 200(OK).

But it doesn't delete anything from the database.

When I step through it using Visual Studio and breakpoints, I see this message in my `Try Catch DbUpdateException` block:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
> row(s).  Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
> loaded.

But I am not sure why.  I think I am doing everything right, but obviously I am not.

In the controller, it's kind of a 3 step delete process.

Because I have to delete related data first, before deleting the actual game catalog.

```
// DELETE: api/GameCatalogs/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<GameCatalog>> DeleteGameCatalog(string id)
{
    var gameCatalog = await _context.GameCatalog.FindAsync(id);
    Catalog<GameCatalog_MediaCatalog> gameMediaRef;
    PlayerCatalog playerRef;

    if (gameCatalog == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // if media exists, delete it all
    if (gameCatalog.MediaId != null)
    {
        gameMediaRef = _context.GameCatalog_MediaCatalog.Where(x => x.MediaId == gameCatalog.MediaId).ToCatalog();
        _context.GameCatalog_MediaCatalog.RemoveRange(gameMediaRef);
    }

    // if a player exists, delete the reference
    if (gameCatalog.PlayerId != null)
    {
        playerRef = _context.PlayerCatalog.Where(x => x.PlayerId == gameCatalog.PlayerId).FirstOrDefault();
        _context.PlayerCatalog.Remove(playerRef);
    }

    // finally we can delete the catalog
    _context.GameCatalog.Remove(gameCatalog);

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {}

    return gameCatalog;
 }
```

Is there something I'm missing or that I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you're eating the exception so the controller thinks everything went fine and sends a `200` statuscode, try something like `return NotFound()` in the catch clause

Comment: @PatrickBeynio oh ok, good idea! Is that why I am seeing the exception, `Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). 
Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. ` because it can't find anything ?

Comment: yes, i think so

Comment: @PatrickBeynio thanks, I tried that, and while it does send a `Not Found`, it still shows the exception message.  Also I checked the database, and the entries do exist, so the delete should find them.

Comment: Is MediaId a string or a number?  The ID may not be matching which could give zero rows.  I would remove the WHERE and see if you get any rows returned.

Comment: @jdweng it is a string ID.  I will try that

Comment: What I don't like, that you have mixed async and sync versions. Anyway, just start transaction before retrieving anything.